# How do you get 100% completion on Academia?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've finished the story and am playing through the post-story to get all the fragments.  I've explored all other maps to 100% EXCEPT Academia.

I'm at 99% on Academia but I don't know how to reach the last bit of the map.  It's a small room at the bottom of the New Town section of the map.  It appears dark on the map which means I haven't explored it but I can't reach it because there's a gate/glass blocking it.

How do I reach this place?  Please help

Answer (score 5):

This is not so bad, just use the escalator to go to the bottom floor and walk *beneath* the dark-coloured area on your map.  You'll get the last 1%.